# Parsing JSON file in Snowflake Database

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image]Database :**SNOWFLAKE**

My table contains JSON data for example:

```
{
    "bucket":"IN_Apps",
    "bySeqno":56,
    "cas":1527639206906626048,
    "content":"eyJoaWdoQmluIjoiNTQ4NTA4MDkiLCJkb2N1bWVudFR5cGUiOiJJSU5ETyIsImNhcmRUeXBlIyayI6Ik1BU1RFUkNBUkQifQ==",
    "event":"mutation",
    "expiration":0,
    "flags":33554432,
    "key":"iin54850809",
    "lockTime":0,
    "partition":948,
    "revSeqno":1,
    "vBucketUuid":137987627737694
}
```

when i tried to parse it.

```
select 
parse_json:bucket::string as bucket ,
parse_json:bySeqno::string as bySeqno ,
parse_json:cas::INT as cas ,
parse_json:content::string as content ,
parse_json:event::string as event 
,parse_json:expiration::string as expiration
,parse_json:flags::string as flags
,parse_json:key::string as key
,parse_json:lockTime::string as lockTime
,parse_json:partition::string as partition
,parse_json:revSeqno::string as revSeqno
,parse_json:vBucketUuid::string as vBucketUuid
from STG_YS_APPS v
```

but it is throwing error like.

> SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 0 invalid identifier > >'PARSE_JSON'

may someone please help me.

Comment: any clue techie please

Comment: What is the _exact_ schema of your table? Do you have there a column name called "parse_json" ? That's what your SQL suggests, but that would be weird. Maybe do "DESC TABLE v" and add the output to the question

Comment: @MarcinZukowski: No i don't have column named as parse_json. it is inbuilt in snowflake for parsing JSON.

Comment: Well, your query is written like you did. Please run "DESC TABLE v" and provide output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Answer with a known schema***

Update: Since you provided schema, which shows a `VAR` column of `VARIANT` type, here's what you need, couldn't be simpler:

```
select
var:bucket::string as bucket,
var:bySeqno::string as bySeqno,
var:cas::int as cas
...
from STG_YS_APPS v
```

***Below the answer before the schema was known***

I'll assume you have a `VARCHAR` (or similar) column in your table that is called `json`, and stores the values you presented. You didn't provide the schema, so please adjust the column name as necessary.

You're not using `PARSE_JSON` as a function in your SQL. You should write something like

```
select
parse_json(json):bucket::string as bucket,
parse_json(json):bySeqno::string as bySeqno,
parse_json(json):cas::int as cas
...
from STG_YS_APPS v
```

Comment: i have attached the snapshot of schema above. when i tried select parse_json(json):bucket::string as bucket from STG_YS_APPS, i got error:  invalid identifier 'JSON . please help if i am missing something

Comment: may someone please help me if possible, Snowflake datawarehouse is little new to me.

Comment: am i need to add lateral flatten

Comment: I'm sorry, but you clearly should do some reading and read/watch some tutorials about SQL in general and Snowflake VARIANT processing... Your questions suggest lack of very basic SQL knowledge.